# Морфинг иконки внутри кнопки svg

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, анимация

Интересно было бы использовать тему плавного морфинга, то есть изменения контуров одной фигуры в контуры другой фигуры в svg кнопках.
Дизайн следующий. В начальном состоянии кнопка имеет иконку - желтая звездочка слева и надпись "Сохранить"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При нажатии на кнопку происходит плавный морфинг звездочки в зеленый чекбокс и надпись "Сохранить" меняется на надпись "Сохранено!"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Понятно, что плавный морфинг достигается изменением координат узловых точек одной фигуры на координаты узловых точек другой фигуры. Я знаю, что для реализации этого должно быть выполнено главное условие - **количество узловых точек в обоих фигурах должно быть одинаковым. И пути (патчи) не должны иметь разрывов.**

Пример иконки звёздочки

```html
<svg width="194.6" height="185.1" viewBox="0 0 194.6 185.1">
  <path fill="#FFD41D" d="M97.3,0 127.4,60.9 194.6,70.7 145.9,118.1 157.4,185.1 97.3,153.5 37.2,185.1 48.6,118.1 0,70.7 67.2,60.9"/>
</svg>
```

Пример иконки чекбокса

```html
<svg width="194.6" height="185.1" viewBox="0 0 194.6 185.1"> 
  <path d="M110,58.2 147.3,0 192.1,29 141.7,105.1 118.7,139.8 88.8,185.1 46.1,156.5 0,125 23.5,86.6 
   71.1,116.7" fill="yellowgreen"/> 
</svg>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Немного ответ не по вопросу, а более общий про svg вообще.

По какой-то причине разработчики брезгают руками рисовать и вообще трогать его (как будто боятся jpg в блокноте увидеть). И это касается даже очень крупных компаний.

Взглянем на логотип РБК ([ссылка](https://s.rbk.ru/v8_top_static/rbc7-8.5.76/mobile/styles/blocks/g-logo-rbc/images/logo.svg))

Как он выглядит у них и как можно сделать:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg width="22px" height="22px" viewBox="0 0 22 22" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <!-- Generator: Sketch 46.2 (44496) - http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch -->
    <title>Group 3</title>
    <desc>Created with Sketch.</desc>
    <defs></defs>
    <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <g id="logo_mob_outline" transform="translate(-25.000000, -140.000000)">
            <g id="Group-3" transform="translate(25.000000, 140.000000)">
                <polygon id="Fill-1" fill="#92CFAE" points="0 0.0390594602 0 19.3656226 19.3265632 0.0390594602"></polygon>
                <polygon id="Fill-2" fill="#2A8288" points="1.69531256 21.0609352 21.0218757 21.0609352 21.0218757 1.73437202"></polygon>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>

<svg width="22px" height="22px" viewBox="0 0 22 22">
  <polygon points="0 19 19 0 0 0" fill="#92CFAE"></polygon>
  <polygon points="1 21 21 1 21 21" fill="#2A8288"></polygon>
</svg>
```

Я на глаз делал, может немного промахнулся, но суть в том, что снаружи он квадрат, а точки не из целого числа создают неприятные неровности на по идее ровных краях. В логотипе Яндекса к примеру тоже лишние группы с лишними атрибутами, с кучей цифр после точки (а ведь реально больше одного знака никогда, никто не заметит разницы)

Ну вернемся к нашей звезде-чекбоксу.
Нет ничего сложного самому нарисовать ее, это не сложнее, чем рисовать ее в тетрадке в клетку:

```html
<svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
  <polygon points="
    0 75,
    75 75,
    100 0,
    125 75,
    200 75,
    140 120,
    166 200,
    100 150,
    34 200,
    60 120" fill="#FF6633"/>
</svg>
```

Чтобы было проще, можно переносить каждую точку на следующую строчку. Я нарисовал обычную советскую звезду в редакторе, как рисовали её в школе, одной линией. Подровнял и получил точки. Кстати теоретически для ровных линий правильнее использовать `polygon`, тк `path` подразумевает возможное наличие кривых безье.

Анимация из ответа очень топорная, без души и в середине анимации сильная каша. Открываю редактор, накладываю одну фигуру на другую и смотрю как можно анимировать менее грубо:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
  <polygon points="0 75 75 75 100 0 125 75 200 75 140 120 166 200 100 150 34 200 60 120" fill="#FF6633">
    <animate begin="click" fill="freeze" attributeName="points" dur="1s" to="35 82 67 120 167 36 193 67 193 67 193 67 114.5 131.5 62 175 62 175 5 108"/>
  </polygon>
</svg>
```

```js
var button = document.getElementById("button"),
  buttonText = document.getElementById("btnText"),
  animationToStar = document.getElementById("toStar"),
  animationToCheck = document.getElementById("toCheck");

button.addEventListener('click', function() {

  if (button.classList.contains("keep")) {
    button.classList.remove("keep");
    animationToStar.beginElement();
    buttonText.innerHTML = "Сохранить";
  } else {
    buttonText.innerHTML = "Сохранено!";
    button.classList.add("keep");
    animationToCheck.beginElement();
  }

}, false);
```

```css
button {
  border: 0;
  background: linear-gradient( to bottom, #444, #111);
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 10px 30px 12px;
  width: 235px;
  outline: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
}

button:hover,
button:active {
  background: black;
}

button svg {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

button span {
  font-size: 22px;
  position: relative;
  top: 4px;
  color: white;
}

body {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<button id="button">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 200 200">
    <polygon points="0 75 75 75 100 0 125 75 200 75 140 120 166 200 100 150 34 200 60 120" fill="#FF6633">
        <animate id="toCheck" fill="freeze" attributeName="points" dur="500ms" begin="indefinite" d="toCheck"
          to="35 82 67 120 167 36 193 67 193 67 193 67 114.5 131.5 62 175 62 175 5 108"
        />
        <animate id="toStar" fill="freeze" attributeName="points" dur="500ms" begin="indefinite" d="toStar"
          to="0 75 75 75 100 0 125 75 200 75 140 120 166 200 100 150 34 200 60 120"
        />
        <animate fill="freeze" dur="500ms" to="#EEDD00" attributeName="fill" begin="toCheck.begin"/>
        <animate fill="freeze" dur="500ms" to="#FF6633" attributeName="fill" begin="toStar.begin"/>
     </polygon>
  </svg>
  <span id="btnText">Сохранить</span>
</button>
```

Вставляем в пример из ответа, смотрим что можно улучшить по svg. В принципе все в порядке, только анимацию цвета можно запускать на старте анимации шэйпа прямо в svg, это немного лишнего из js выкидывает.

Comment: Отличный ответ!

Comment: @Artem Gorlachev на вкус и цвет, как говорится у каждого свои фломастеры. Мне вот например в вашей трансформации не нравится, что правый верхний луч звезды торчит одиноко, какое-то время, пока его не накроет правая сторона чекбокса. Да не в этом суть, мне кажется у вас большой потенциал и будет более конструктивно не критиковать весь мир разработчиков, а включится в активное продвижение SVG

Comment: @Artem Gorlachev выбрал ваше решение

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, да, торчит, у меня звезда острее и перелом один, но глобально да, согласен. Ответ у меня скорее просто описывает процесс как это делать руками.

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev я думаю вас заинтересует вот эта статья `Ana Tudor` по ручному созданию анимации звезды -  в сердце Потрясающая работа!  https://css-tricks.com/creating-star-heart-animation-svg-vanilla-javascript/

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, у Анны все работы шикарные:))

Comment: этот ответ вообще с css-tricks угнали полностью ... я искал инфу по морфингу и наткнулся на много статей и увидел на ruSO копию примера css-tricks только у них ТАМ classList называется по другому а ответ полная копия .... хм

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, не этот ответ, а другой ответ здесь. Я его скопировал. А вообще этот вопрос (и первый ответ) просто перевод с en stackoverflow, так что это там упер кто-то

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev   я просто увидел 100% совпадение ... да здесь много кто так делает ... редко вижу уникальные ответы ...авторские .. самодельные

Answer (score 12):

### Пример морфинга иконки звездочки в чекбокс.

*Запуск анимации - клик на фигуре.*

```html
<svg width="194.6" height="185.1" viewBox="0 0 194.6 185.1">
  <path fill="#FFD41D" d="M97.3,0 127.4,60.9 194.6,70.7 145.9,118.1 157.4,185.1 97.3,153.5 37.2,185.1 48.6,118.1 0,70.7 67.2,60.9">
    <animate id="anCheck" begin="click" fill="freeze" attributeName="d" dur="1s" from="M97.3,0 127.4,60.9 194.6,70.7 145.9,118.1 157.4,185.1 97.3,153.5 37.2,185.1 48.6,118.1 0,70.7 67.2,60.9"  to="M110,58.2 147.3,0 192.1,29 141.7,105.1 118.7,139.8 88.8,185.1 46.1,156.5 0,125 23.5,86.6  71.1,116.7"/>
    <animate id="anGreen" begin="anCheck.end" fill="freeze" attributeName="fill" dur="500ms" to="#53B848"></animate>
  </path> 
</svg>
```

Анимация достигается плавным изменением координат узловых точек, которые находятся в атрибуте "d" патча.

Анимация изменения цвета выполняет команда:

```
<animate id="anGreen" begin="anCheck.end" fill="freeze" attributeName="fill" dur="500ms" to="#53B848"></animate>
```

Осталось написать правила `CSS` для стилизации кнопки и `JS` скрипт для переключения состояний кнопки путем добавления, удаления классов и запуска анимаций.

*Запуск анимации - клик на фигуре.*

```js
var icon = document.getElementById("button"),
  buttonText = document.getElementById("btnText"),
  animationToStar = document.getElementById("anStar"),
  animationToCheck = document.getElementById("anCheck"),
  animationToYellow = document.getElementById("anYellow"),
  animationToGreen = document.getElementById("anGreen");

button.addEventListener('click', function() {

  if (button.classList.contains("keep")) {
    button.classList.remove("keep");
    animationToStar.beginElement();
    animationToYellow.beginElement();
    buttonText.innerHTML = "Сохранить";
  } else {
    buttonText.innerHTML = "Сохранено!";
    button.classList.add("keep");
    animationToCheck.beginElement();
    animationToGreen.beginElement();

  }

}, false);
```

```css
button {
  border: 0;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient( top, #444, #111);
  background: linear-gradient( to bottom, #444, #111);
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 10px 30px 12px;
  outline: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 235px;
  text-align: left;
}

button:hover,
button:active {
  background: black;
}

button svg {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

button span {
  font-size: 22px;
  position: relative;
  top: 4px;
  color: white;
}

body {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<button id="button">
<svg viewBox="0 0 194.6 185.1">
  <polygon fill="#FFD41D" points="97.3,0 127.4,60.9 194.6,70.7 145.9,118.1 157.4,185.1 97.3,153.5 37.2,185.1 48.6,118.1 0,70.7 
   67.2,60.9">
    <animate id="anCheck" begin="indefinite" fill="freeze" attributeName="points" dur="500ms" to="110,58.2 147.3,0 192.1,29 141.7,105.1 118.7,139.8 88.8,185.1 46.1,156.5 0,125 23.5,86.6 
   71.1,116.7"/>
    <animate id="anGreen" begin="indefinite" fill="freeze" attributeName="fill" dur="500ms" to="#53B848"></animate>
    <animate id="anStar" begin="indefinite" fill="freeze" attributeName="points" dur="500ms" to="97.3,0 127.4,60.9 194.6,70.7 145.9,118.1 157.4,185.1 97.3,153.5 37.2,185.1 48.6,118.1 0,70.7 
   67.2,60.9"/>
    <animate id="anYellow" begin="indefinite" fill="freeze" attributeName="fill" dur="500ms" to="#FFD41D"></animate>
  </polygon>
</svg>
<span id="btnText">Сохранить</span>
</button>
```