# Какие программы и генераторы можно применять для облегчения написания кода svg

Tags: javascript, css, svg, поиск-программ

Какую посоветуете программу для SVG?

Желательно с "генерацией кода" HTML, если есть такое.

Update

Автор вопроса видимо имел ввиду программы для помощи в написании кода svg

Comment: Adobe Illustrator

Comment: Иллюстратор сейчас лучше всех, все эти генераторы, скетчи итп делают вывод, что его потом в текстовом редакторе почти невозможно подправить.

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev я помню ты мне говорил что ты не пользуешься редакторами для svg  а всё пишешь с нуля - руками ....

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский, это было касательно какого-то примера со звездой, в реальной жизни дизайнеры присылают убитые скетчем иконки, которые как раз иллюстратором и приводятся в редактируемый вид.

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev хоть раз ты сказал правду ...

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский, я не припомню, чтобы врал где-то. Вот мой ответ, про который, вы видимо говорите, я описываю что берем люстру, смотрим точки итп https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/797267/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3-%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8-svg/810827#810827

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev я не про это говорил ...ладно комментарии не для этого предназначены

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**Update**

---

Посмотрите конец топика. Добавлена утилита, которая сделает из вашего статичного SVG файла  анимацию рисования линий с помощью нажатия одной кнопки.

---

Автору, если я правильно понял вопрос нужны инструменты, которые облегчают написание кода SVG.

- [SVG GENERATOR PATH](https://smooth.ie/blogs/news/svg-wavey-transitions-between-sections)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Очень удобная вещь.

Перемещаете узловые точки, двигаете рычаги, а внизу пишется код патча.

Может быть использован для написания кода для фигурной шапки сайта, для анимашек волн и т.д и т.п

*Полученный код из генераторов, в период освоения SVG, лучше добавлять инлайн способом, то есть непосредственным копированием в `HTML`*

---

[Make some waves!](https://getwaves.io/)

Ещё один генератор волн. Имеется возможность выбирать форму волны от прямоугольных до кривых Безье.

---

- [Path Length Calculator](https://codepen.io/gabriellewee/pen/EZPYmw)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Копируете формулу `path` и получаете его максимальную длину.

Вычисление длины `path` необходима для написания кода анимации рисования линий, посредством изменения атрибута `stroke-dasharray`

- [SVG Path Builder](https://codepen.io/anthonydugois/pen/mewdyZ)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добавляете, удаляете, перемещаете узловые точки для получения нужной формы кривой. В нижнем правом углу автоматом пишется код `path`

- [BOXY SVG](https://boxy-svg.com/)

Быстрый, многофункциональный векторный редактор

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### Генераторы clipPath

- https://codepen.io/jh3y/pen/XqVQqa
- http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/
- https://betravis.github.io/shape-tools/polygon-drawing/

**Update 13.11.2023**

---

### Генераторы feColorMatrix

- https://fecolormatrix.com/   автор Rik Shennink
- https://codepen.io/mullany/pen/DmEYLg автор Michael Mullany

---

### Генераторы базовых фигур SVG

- [Генератор прямых линий](https://svg-art.ru/?p=1388)
- [Прямые отрезки – path](https://svg-art.ru/?p=1112)
- [Генератор прямоугольников](https://svg-art.ru/?p=1392)
- [Генератор окружностей](https://svg-art.ru/?p=1395)
- [Генератор эллипсов](https://svg-art.ru/?p=1398)

### Генераторы кривых Безье

- [Кубическая кривая Безье – The cubic Bezier curve](https://svg-art.ru/?p=1114)
- [Кривые Безье второго порядка](https://svg-art.ru/?p=1116)
- [Гладкая поликривая Безье второго порядка](https://svg-art.ru/?p=1118)

Принцип для всех, вышеперечисленных генераторов svg кода одинаков: двигаете узловые точки, перемещаете их рычаги и копируете код SVG.

Процесс использования генераторов нагляден, удобен,  сразу видно какие атрибуты `path` динамически изменяются. Что помогает понять, как они работают.
Также их выгодно применять, так как на выходе получается чистый код, без добавления служебной информации, которую вносят векторные редакторы в файл SVG

### Конвертеры

**Конвертер SVG path**

[Convert SVG path to all-relative or all-absolute](https://codepen.io/leaverou/pen/RmwzKv)

Преобразует все команды либо в относительную, либо в абсолютную форму записи.

[URL-encoder for SVG](https://yoksel.github.io/url-encoder/)

**Конвертер букв в path**

[Google font to SVG path](https://danmarshall.github.io/google-font-to-svg-path/)

Для получения SVG кода, реализующего контур буквы, необходимо выбрать шрифт, размер и написать букву или слово.

**Конвертеры из растрового формата в векторный**

- [*Convert image to the SVG format*](https://image.online-convert.com/ru/convert-to-svg)

Бесплатный онлайн конвертер позволяет конвертировать изображения в формат SVG (Scalable Vector Graphics) (внимание! бета-версия конвертера). Вы можете как загрузить файл, так и указать ссылку на изображение. Вы также можете наложить цифровые эффекты.

- [*Vector Magic*](https://vectormagic.com/)  (платный 10$)

Позволяет быстро произвести  векторизацию или трассировку —  процесс получения растрового изображения и его перерисовку в векторное изображение.

**Инструменты разработки**

К сожалению ничего, такого, специализированного нет. Да в принципе и не нужно особо.
Так как svg легко правится в текстовом редакторе, например: `Notepad++`
Рисовать сложные фигуры можно в векторных редакторах: `Inkscape`, `Adobe Illustrator`.

Для рисования простых фигур есть и такие редакторы:

- [editor.method](https://editor.method.ac/)
- [svg-edit.github.io](https://svg-edit.github.io/svgedit/releases/latest/editor/svg-editor.html)
- [Draw SVG](http://www.drawsvg.org/drawsvg.html)
- [JXNBLK / PATHS](http://jxnblk.com/paths/?d=M0%200%20L0%2028%20C10%2046%2030%2060%2064%2048%20L64%200%20Z)
- [SVG Path Editor](https://aydos.com/svgedit/) (aydos.com)
- [SVG Path Editor](https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/) (yqnn.github.io)
- [Генератор волн](https://getwaves.io/)
- [SVG Stroke Recorder](https://codepen.io/osublake/pen/Bzamom) (Рисование линий с помощью мышки)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Оптимизаторы кода SVG**

- [SVGOMG](https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/) - автор Jake Archibald
- [SVGO-GUI](https://github.com/svg/svgo-gui) - автор GreLI

Убирается вся лишняя, служебная информация, можно задать количество знаков после запятой у `path`.
Размер файла svg порою сокращается в несколько раз и код становится читабельным.

**Update 4.12.2019**

### Генераторы параметров атрибутов для анимации

1. [Cubic-bezier](https://cubic-bezier.com/#.17,.67,.83,.67)
2. [Генератор keysplines](http://svg-art.ru/?p=1599)
3. [Генератор keyTimes](https://svg-art.ru/?p=1674)
4. [Генератор анимации линий](https://maxwellito.github.io/vivus-instant/)
   Всё просто: перетаскиваете свой файл SVG в окно загрузки утилиты и получаете на выходе готовый файл с анимацией рисования линии.

**Update 30.11.2023**

- **Генератор QR-кода в формате SVG**

[php-пакет composer endroid/qr-code](https://github.com/endroid/qr-code)

Comment: это призыв забацать тут ответ про d3? ))

Comment: @Stranger in the Q Я просто набрёл на простенький  векторный редактор, в котором можно быстро получить патч без лишнего мусора и добавил ссылку в свою подборку подобных инструментов.

Comment: Ну окей, тогда не буду, в засаде посижу =))

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Добавляй, если есть желание отдельным ответом, - больше инструментов, больше пользы

Comment: @Alexandr_TT по моему инкскапе отлично справляется со всём перечисленном

Comment: @De.Minov Удален оптимизатор кода - **SVG Editor** - автор Peter Collingridge. Так как автор удалил его со своего сайта