# Responsive clip-path

Tags: css, css3, svg, адаптивная-верстка, clip-path

В следующем примере блок `main` (синезелёный градиент) обрезается при помощи `clip-path` и принимает форму сердечка. Однако видно, что он обрезается в масштабе 1:1, а хотелось бы, чтобы форма обрезки растягивалась по размеру блока (по аналогии с тем, как у `background-size` работает `cover`, `contain` или `100% 100%`).

https://jsfiddle.net/a5goLyds/

```css
html, body, main {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

svg {
  width: 10em;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

main {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, green, blue);
  clip-path: url(#heart-clip);
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <path id="heart" fill="orange" stroke="red"
    d="M 10,30
       A 20,20 0,0,1 50,30
       A 20,20 0,0,1 90,30
       Q 90,60 50,90
       Q 10,60 10,30 z"
  />

  <clipPath id="heart-clip">
    <use xlink:href="#heart" />
  </clipPath>
</svg>

<main></main>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

К сожалению я не нашёл `clip-path` генераторов, которые позволяли бы рисовать кривыми линиями.

Есть генераторы, которые рисуют прямыми линиями по узловым точкам:

1. https://codepen.io/jh3y/pen/XqVQqa
2. http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

Для многоугольника получаю вот такие значения

```
clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 80% 10%, 100% 35%, 100% 70%, 80% 90%, 50% 100%, 20% 90%, 0% 70%, 0% 35%, 20% 10%);
```

Преобразую для `svg clip-path` в доли от единицы:

```
<polygon points="0.5,0 0.8,0.1 1,0.35 1,0.7 0.8,0.9 0.5,1 0.20,0.9  0,0.7 0,0.35 0.2,0.1" />
```

Чтобы получить масштабируемый `clip-path`, например при наведении курсора, нужно менять размер изображения в сторону увеличения, соответственно увеличится и `clip-path`, обрезая это изображение.

```css
svg {}

main {
  width: 15%;
  height: 15%;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, green, blue);
  clip-path: url(#heart-clip);
  transition: 1s;
}

main:hover {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 1 1" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"> 
  <defs>
   <clipPath id="heart-clip" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
     <polygon  
     points="0.5,0 0.8,0.1 1,0.35 1,0.7 
     0.8,0.9 0.5,1 0.20,0.9  0,0.7 0,0.35 0.2,0.1" />
   </clipPath>
  </defs>
  </svg>
</main>
```

Comment: Полезные ссылки

Comment: @kizoso Есть топик, где собираю  полезные генераторы кода для SVG https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/925990/28748

Answer (score 3):

Ничего не меняя в авторском примере - ввожу туда:

```
<use xlink:href="#heart" transform="scale(5), translate(-10 -10)"/>
```

Итог:

```css
html,
body,
main {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

svg {
  width: 10em;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

main {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, green, blue);
  clip-path: url(#heart-clip);
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <path id="heart" fill="orange" stroke="red"
    d="M 10,30
       A 20,20 0,0,1 50,30
       A 20,20 0,0,1 90,30
       Q 90,60 50,90
       Q 10,60 10,30 z"
  />

  <clipPath id="heart-clip">
    <use xlink:href="#heart" transform="scale(6), translate(-10 -10)"/>
  </clipPath>
</svg>

<main></main>
```

В результате можно добиться любой пропорции и положения патча, регулируя лишь
`transform="scale(what), translate(x y)"`

**Однако это ещё не всё.**

Там, где было `<clipPath id="heart-clip">`, добавим `clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox"`, но при этом не забудем подкорректировать  `scale()`, чтобы результат от "d" всегда был меньше единицы, как у Александра в полигоне.
- И вот оно, долгожданное счастье!

- [Responsive clip-path!!!](https://codepen.io/warsan/pen/roJmvb)

В песочнице будет легче менять размеры рабочей области, чтобы убедиться в искомой "респонсивности" элемента.
Но пробуем описать его и здесь:

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, #666, #222, #666, #ea8, #666, #222, #666, #8ce, #666 4%) fixed;
}

svg {
  width: 10rem;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

main {
  height: 100vw;
  clip-path: url(#heart-clip);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, blue, red, green, transparent 70%);
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" 
xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <path id="heart" fill="orange" stroke="red"
    d="M 10,30
       A 20,20 0,0,1 50,30
       A 20,20 0,0,1 90,30
       Q 90,60 50,90
       Q 10,60 10,30 z" />

  <clipPath id="heart-clip" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
    <use xlink:href="#heart" transform="scale(.007,.007), translate(-6 -6)"/>
  </clipPath>
</svg>

<main></main>
```

Comment: Это всё равно фиксированный размер - responsive не получится.

Comment: @Qwertiy, - Да, это тоже не респонсив... 
(только больше ничё на ум нейдёт)))

Comment: @Qwertiy, - А вот на второй вариант ответа можем и "глазку положить"...(несомненно в нём что-то есть)))

Comment: @ВарламЕрофеич вы настоящий экспериментатор! Разработчики svg никогда не дошли бы до такого способа, им это даже и не приснится никогда :)))) Это ж надо так извернуться.  Вот что значит научный тык! Проще было `d="M 10,30` из пикселей в доли от единицы перевести :))) А плюс я вам ещё вчера поставил :)

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, - Спасибо, но вот описал-то я "енту оказию" дюже скомканно. Поймёт ли читатель, что коэффициент масштабирования подбирается таким, чтобы результат перемножения на координату плавал в пределах от 0 до 1... (?)

Comment: Да, интересно. Тоже плюсанул.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы реализовал так, а градиент уже реализовал бы в самом SVG

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #242424;
}

main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml, <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox=" 0 0 100 100" width="100%" height="100%"><path id="heart" fill="orange" stroke="red" d="M 10,30 A 20,20 0,0,1 50,30  A 20,20 0,0,1 90,30 Q 90,60 50,90 Q 10,60 10,30 z"></path>);</svg>');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<main></main>
```

Comment: Так вопрос же не про это...

Comment: Вижу, что не про это, просто на мой взгляд это лучше, чем `clip-path  CSS`