# Масштабируемый clipPath

Tags: css, svg, анимация, clip-path

Суть в том, что svg фигура в clipPath отрисовывается как есть, по тем самым размерам, с которыми создана.

Есть ли способ, при котором обрезаемая область масштабировалась бы по размерам блока.

```css
 .img-holder {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        /* По горизонтальной полосе прокрутки окна понимаем, что Ширина блока больше чем 
        область обрезки svg */
        width: 1550px;
        height: 350px;
    }
    
    .clip-svg-inlinetv {
      /* Фактическая ширина фигуры 350px на 250px */
        -webkit-clip-path: url("#clip-polygontv");
        clip-path: url("#clip-polygontv");
    }
```

```html
 <span class="img-holder clip-svg-inlinetv">
          <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGmV9.jpg" alt="">
    </span>
    
    
    <svg>
        <defs>
            <clipPath id="clip-polygontv" >
                <path d="M338.5,22.5c24.8,75.6,2.1,205.1,0,205.7c-172.1,50.5-328.6-0.4-328.6-0.4c-22.2-102.2,0-205.2,0-205.2
      C179.4-27.2,337.8,20.6,338.5,22.5z" />
            </clipPath>
        </defs>
    </svg>
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dhu8wona/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Немного теории**

[clipPathUnits](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/clipPathUnits) - атрибут указывает, какую систему координат использовать для содержимого элемента `<clipPath>`.

`clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox"`

Это значение указывает, что все координаты внутри элемента `<clipPath>` относятся к ограничительной рамке элемента, к которому применяется обрезаемый контур. Это означает, что источником системы координат является верхний левый угол ограничивающего прямоугольника объекта, а ширина и высота ограничивающего прямоугольника объекта имеют длину в 1 единицу.

Другими словами все размеры указываются в долях от единицы. Например для прямоугольника, который займёт всё пространство это будет выглядеть так :

`<rect width="1" height="1" rx="0.25" />`

Чтобы получить масштабируемый `clip-path`, например при наведении курсора, нужно менять размер изображения в сторону увеличения, соответственно увеличится и `clip-path`, обрезая это изображение.

```css
img {
width:25%;
height:25%;
clip-path:url(#clip-polygon2);
transition:2s ;
}
img:hover {
width:50%;
height:50%;

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
       <img src="https://i-a.d-cd.net/1cda2es-960.jpg" alt="">
</div>
    
    <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
            <defs>
                <clipPath id="clip-polygon2"   clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox" >
                    <rect width="1" height="1" rx="0.25" ry="0.25" />
                </clipPath>
            </defs>
     </svg>
```

Comment: превосходно! Только одно "но" - как то же самое проделать с path? У меня она вообще не отображается при использовании clipPathUnits (как было в изначальных примерах предыдущего вопроса, если помните)

Comment: @Amsterdam конечно помню, но у вас уже достаточно много примеров, чтобы проанализировать все варианты и построить свой рабочий вариант. Главное условие  патч переводить из пикселей в доли от единицы если используется `clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox" ` Посмотрите ещё один ответ на эту тему https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/932206/responsive-clip-path

Comment: забавно, совершенно аналогичный вопрос. Но в том примере так же используется фигура. С path тоже используются доли, но получается в итоге белая область. Не могу понять почему https://jsfiddle.net/w5fc23h4/

Comment: @Amsterdam в примере по вашей ссылке использован `clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox"` а `path` не в долях от единицы. Вы кроме ссылки на другой топик мой комментарий выше не прочли?

Comment: @Amsterdam какая-то сборная солянка в вашем примере `rx=0.25` `ry=0.25` причём вообще? Это же радиусы для прямоугольника. А у вас патч

Comment: я прочел все комментарии и просомтрел примеры, но видимо не понял, что значит "перевести в доли от единицы" и как это сделать..

Comment: @Amsterdam 100% это 1  единица. 50%  - 0.5  `<rect width="1" height="1" rx="0.25" ry="0.25" />` прямоугольник, который занимает 100% в ширину и высоту rx - радиус закругления вот и получилась форма clip-path в виде TV Берите и пользуйтесь

Comment: извините, возможно я сегодня крайне туп, но если с простой фигурой понятно как действовать, то при использовании <path d="M338. ... ,22.5z" /> с кучей значений, как их все переводить, врчную?

Comment: @Amsterdam ну зачем же так :) Это вина современного образования, а у вас есть стремление понять, разобраться, это уже огромный плюс. Задайте отдельный вопрос Да, придется переводить вручную, так как подходящих генераторов clip-path в долях от единицы, я не нашёл

Comment: во времена моего образования, оно еще не было таким уж современным. Тогда еще жил IE7 и на защите диплома, мой сайт смотрели в нем, к сожалению) При этом, svg так плотно мне потребовалось изучить только сейчас, до этого удавалось обходится. Но это совсем лирика. Касательно перевода вручную - понял, спасибо. Печальный, конечно, расклад, но раз так, то и отдельный вопрос не требуется задавать в таком случае.

Comment: @Amsterdam понял, тогда давайте закрывать вопрос, как решение

Comment: ну, давайте. Хотя я использовал иное решение, косвенное, но вопрос тем не менее помогло решить в таком виде, с <path ="">. Напишу его сейчас сюда тоже, но решением отмечу вас, т.к. он к вопросу относится напрямую и хоть и вручную, но позволяет решить вопрос

Comment: @Amsterdam публикуйте, чем больше вариантов, тем лучше.

Answer (score 1):

Тем не менее, использовал косвенное решение, и даже немного костыльное, которое непосредственно clipPath не масштабирует, однако вопрос решить позволило.

1. Создаем несколько фигур, задавая их размер сразу при создании в векторном редакторе.
2. Загружаем в документ под разными id, например, **#clip-polygontv**, **#clip-polygontv2**
3. В CSS для определенного разрешения экрана указываем свой clip-path

   @max-width (media: 1920px) {
   .clip-svg-inlinetv {
    -webkit-clip-path: url("#clip-polygontv");
           clip-path: url("#clip-polygontv");
   }
   }

   @max-width (media: 1024px) {
   .clip-svg-inlinetv {
    -webkit-clip-path: url("#clip-polygontv2");
           clip-path: url("#clip-polygontv2");
   }
   }

Таким образом, обрезаемая область по ходу изменения разрешения экрана будет меняться, благодаря использованию фигур разных размеров.

Comment: нормальное решение (+)

Answer (score 0):

Как уже выше писали, нужно добавить к `<clipPath>` атрибут `clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox"`, и перевести координаты `path=""` в доли единицы (лично я воспользовался вот этим сервисом - https://yoksel.github.io/relative-clip-path/). Может кому-то поможет :)