# Создание прелоадера SVG не круглой формы

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, svg

Необходимо создать SVG прелоадер для сайта, но не умею работать с самими SVG (рисовать правильно). Идея такая:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При загрузке индикатором выступает градиентная полоска, которая постепенно заполняет объект, попыток решения нет, т.к. для этого нужно нарисовать саму SVG и как-то через `path` (наверно) выставлять уже значения заполнения.

Подскажите, как можно это сделать?

Comment: а как должны выглядеть другие кадры? почему линия скошенная, это имитация воды?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот вариант с маской, путь ровный т.к. подбирал точки дуги и кривой Безье перебором =)

Фокус с покачивающимся окончанием линии сделан при помощи вращающегося прямоугольника, который закрыт той же маской, за которой прячется и градиентный фон.

```js
requestAnimationFrame(frame);

function frame(t){
  fill.setAttribute('stroke-dasharray', `${t/40} 1000`);
  let p1 = fill.getPointAtLength(t/40);
  let p2 = fill.getPointAtLength(t/40+2);
  let dy = p2.y - p1.y;
  let dx = p2.x - p1.x;
  let a = dy - dx ? Math.atan2(dy, dx)*180/Math.PI+90+Math.sin(t/280)*20 : 90;
  end.setAttribute('transform', `translate(${p1.x},${p1.y})rotate(${a})`);
  requestAnimationFrame(frame);
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox=0,0,100,100 height=100vh>
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="Grad1" x2="100%" y2="0%" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <stop offset="10%" stop-color="#D3D0FB" />
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#FDE4E2" />
    </linearGradient>
    <mask id="mask">
      <path stroke=white stroke-width=10 fill=none d='
        m20,80
        v-45
        a11,11,0,0,1,20,-5
        c5,5,5,35,10,40
        a11,11,0,0,0,20,-5
        v-45
      '></path>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <rect width=100 height=100 mask=url(#mask) fill="url(#Grad1)"/>
  <path mask=url(#mask) id=fill stroke=blue stroke-width=11 fill=none d='
      m20,81
      v-46
      a11,11,0,0,1,20,-5
      c5,5,5,35,10,40
      a11,11,0,0,0,20,-5
      v-46
  '></path>
  <g mask=url(#mask)>
    <rect id=end fill=blue x=-10 y=-3 width=20 height=6></rect>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: тут основная трудность закрасить фигуру SVG, которая имеет градиент. А для этого это должен быть замкнутый контур а не  широкая, одиночная кривая линия, как в твоем примере.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT теперь как надо

Comment: нормально, на мой взгляд чуть медленнее надо

Comment: @Андрей нет проблем, главное -разобрались, однако вариантов как это сделать -не один, как Вы догададись

Answer (score 4):

### Решение SVG filter

Как возможный вариант решения, так как ТС не указал в деталях способ заполнения лоадера.

**Горизонтальное заполнение:**

```css
.container {
width:50%;
height:50%;

}
#path1 {
fill:url(#Grad1);
filter: url(#violet-fill);

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="286" height="274" viewBox="0 0 143 137" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
<defs>
 <linearGradient id="Grad1" x2="100%" y2="0%" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <stop offset="10%" stop-color="#D3D0FB" />
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#FDE4E2" />
      
      </linearGradient>
  
<filter  id="violet-fill" x="0%" y="0%">
      <feFlood flood-color="#5050E1" />
      <feOffset dx="-120">
        <animate
          id="anim"
          attributeName="dx"
          values="-120;0"
          dur="5s"
          begin="0s"
          repeatCount="indefinite"
          restart="whenNotActive"
          fill="freeze"/> 
      </feOffset>
      <feComposite operator="in" in2="SourceGraphic" />
      <feComposite operator="over" in2="SourceGraphic" />
    </filter> 
 
</defs>
<path id="path1" fill="url(#Grad1)" d="m17 108c0 0-0.2-31.9 0.4-49 1-29.5 40.3-35.3 47.7-11.3 2.7 8.8 8.1 29.3 12.4 36.5 9.9 16.9 24.1 7.7 24.2-0.4 0.1-13.4 0.1-49.5 0.1-49.5l13.8 0c0 0 0.7 34.5 0.4 49.7-0.2 8.9-5.8 19.6-14.2 22.8-18.6 7.2-32.6 2.1-40.8-22.8-2.9-8.7-3.5-11.5-7-25-3.5-13.4-21-13.4-22.6 0-1.3 11.4-0.2 48.2-0.2 48.2z" />


</svg>
</div>
```

**Вертикальное заполнение:**

```css
.container {
width:50%;
height:50%;

}
#path1 {
fill:url(#Grad1);
filter: url(#violet-fill);

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="286" height="274" viewBox="0 0 143 137" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
<defs>
 <linearGradient id="Grad1" x2="100%" y2="0%" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <stop offset="10%" stop-color="#D3D0FB" />
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#FDE4E2" />
      
      </linearGradient>
  
<filter  id="violet-fill" x="0%" y="0%">
      <feFlood flood-color="#5050E1" />
      <feOffset dy="-120">
        <animate
          id="anim"
          attributeName="dy"
          values="-120;0"
          dur="5s"
          begin="0s"
          repeatCount="indefinite"
          restart="whenNotActive"
          fill="freeze"/> 
      </feOffset>
      <feComposite operator="in" in2="SourceGraphic" />
      <feComposite operator="over" in2="SourceGraphic" />
    </filter> 
 
</defs>
<path id="path1" fill="url(#Grad1)" d="m17 108c0 0-0.2-31.9 0.4-49 1-29.5 40.3-35.3 47.7-11.3 2.7 8.8 8.1 29.3 12.4 36.5 9.9 16.9 24.1 7.7 24.2-0.4 0.1-13.4 0.1-49.5 0.1-49.5l13.8 0c0 0 0.7 34.5 0.4 49.7-0.2 8.9-5.8 19.6-14.2 22.8-18.6 7.2-32.6 2.1-40.8-22.8-2.9-8.7-3.5-11.5-7-25-3.5-13.4-21-13.4-22.6 0-1.3 11.4-0.2 48.2-0.2 48.2z" />


</svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

> Может программу какую-нибудь посоветуете или что-то в этом роде?
>   ресурс?

Чтобы нарисовать svg фигуру нужен векторный редактор или для рисования кривых Безье какой-нибудь генератор. [В этом топике](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/925990/28748) даны примеры и ссылки на подобного рода инструменты для рисования патчей.

### Создание патча по заданной форме на рисунке:

- Загружаем картинку кривой в векторный редактор и наносим узловые
  точки с помощью инструмента - <kbd>Рисовать кривые Безье</kbd>  На
  рисунке это красные стрелки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Рычагами управления (синие стрелки) придаем нужную форму кривой,
  чтобы она совпадала с контурами фигуры.
- Сохраняем файл в формате `*.svg`
- Добавляем градиент

```css
.container {
width:50%;
height:50%;

}
#path1 {
fill:url(#Grad1);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="286" height="274" viewBox="0 0 143 137" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
<defs>
 <linearGradient id="Grad1" x2="100%" y2="0%" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <stop offset="10%" stop-color="#D3D0FB" />
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#FDE4E2" />
 </linearGradient>
</defs>
<path id="path1" fill="url(#Grad1)" d="m17 108c0 0-0.2-31.9 0.4-49 1-29.5 40.3-35.3 47.7-11.3 2.7 8.8 8.1 29.3 12.4 36.5 9.9 16.9 24.1 7.7 24.2-0.4 0.1-13.4 0.1-49.5 0.1-49.5l13.8 0c0 0 0.7 34.5 0.4 49.7-0.2 8.9-5.8 19.6-14.2 22.8-18.6 7.2-32.6 2.1-40.8-22.8-2.9-8.7-3.5-11.5-7-25-3.5-13.4-21-13.4-22.6 0-1.3 11.4-0.2 48.2-0.2 48.2z" />


</svg>
</div>
```

### Создание  анимации

Можно использовать анимацию с помощью изменения `stroke-dashoffset` от максимума до нуля.

Для создания path, кривой линии, вдоль которой будет идти  анимация закраски фигуры, снова используем векторный редактор:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чтобы линия заполняла всю фигуру по ширине, задаем - `stroke-width:15.5px;`

```css
.container {
width:50%;
height:50%;

}

#path2 {
stroke-width:15.5;
stroke:#5050E1;
fill:none;
stroke-dasharray: 240 240;
  stroke-dashoffset: 240;
animation: draw 6s 1s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes draw {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 240;
  }

  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}   
</style>
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="286" height="274" viewBox="0 0 143 137" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">


<path id="path2" d="m23.2 107.6c0 0 0.4-31.5 0.2-48.6-0.2-24 32.7-26.2 39.9 0.4 2.4 8.8 3.1 16.6 5.8 24.6 7.8 23 39.2 23.8 39.1-0.4-0.1-17 0.3-47.7 0.3-47.7" />
</svg>
</div>
```

### Собираем всё вместе

Фигуру svg c градиентом и анимацию её заполнения:

```css
.container {
width:50%;
height:50%;

}
#path1 {
fill:url(#Grad1);

}
#path2 {
stroke-width:15.5;
stroke:#5050E1;
fill:none;
stroke-dasharray: 240 240;
  stroke-dashoffset: 240;
animation: draw 6s 1s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes draw {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 240;
  }

  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="286" height="274" viewBox="0 0 143 137" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
<defs>
 <linearGradient id="Grad1" x2="100%" y2="0%" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <stop offset="10%" stop-color="#D3D0FB" />
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#FDE4E2" />
      
      </linearGradient>
</defs>
<path id="path1" fill="url(#Grad1)" d="m17 108c0 0-0.2-31.9 0.4-49 1-29.5 40.3-35.3 47.7-11.3 2.7 8.8 8.1 29.3 12.4 36.5 9.9 16.9 24.1 7.7 24.2-0.4 0.1-13.4 0.1-49.5 0.1-49.5l13.8 0c0 0 0.7 34.5 0.4 49.7-0.2 8.9-5.8 19.6-14.2 22.8-18.6 7.2-32.6 2.1-40.8-22.8-2.9-8.7-3.5-11.5-7-25-3.5-13.4-21-13.4-22.6 0-1.3 11.4-0.2 48.2-0.2 48.2z" />

<path id="path2" d="m23.2 107.6c0 0 0.4-31.5 0.2-48.6-0.2-24 32.7-26.2 39.9 0.4 2.4 8.8 3.1 16.6 5.8 24.6 7.8 23 39.2 23.8 39.1-0.4-0.1-17 0.3-47.7 0.3-47.7" />
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Кривовато получается на [сгибах](https://i.imgur.com/Bcag9Oy.png).. Что если само "заполнение" сделать шире и поверх неё сделать маску формы?

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 нужно просто аккуратней нарисовать, а с маской хороший вариант, но её тоже нужно аккуратно нарисовать :)

Comment: ну тогда проще просто аккуратнее нарисовать "заполнение"))

Comment: @Андрей Рад, что помогло и вам спасибо за интересный вопрос. Андрей, а ещё можно благодарить, отвечающих участников плюсиками, если понравились ответы.