# Пиксилизация SVG

Tags: css3, svg, inkscape

Имеется вектор, при больших размерах он имеет хорошие границы, но при уменьшении размера от 25px - вектор начинает себя вести очень странно! Появляется эффект  пиксилизации на границах!

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 800 800"><g stroke="#fff" stroke-miterlimit="10"><use xlink:href="#B"/><use xlink:href="#B" y="252"/><use xlink:href="#B" y="496"/></g><defs ><path id="B" d="M780.5 169.6a42 42 0 0 1-41.9 41.9H61.3a42 42 0 0 1-41.9-41.9v-.8a42 42 0 0 1 41.9-41.9h677.3a42 42 0 0 1 41.9 41.9v.8z"/></defs></svg>
```

Иконка в `50px`

[image: Вектор в размере width: 50px;]

Иконка в `20px`

[image: Вектор в размере width: 20px;]

Как видно у вектора у которого `width:20px;` появились серые или полупрозрачные полоски. Можно ли от них как либо избавится, может не правильно нарисован сам вектор?

Уже в стилях прописал    `shape-rendering: geometricPrecision;`

В illustrator были взяты простые прямоугольники и сделаны закругления. Как можно исправить это?

Бывает что на определенных размерах вектор выглядит идеально, а на некоторых отвратительно.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Пиксилизация происходит из-за того, что  координаты имеют дробную часть.
 В вашем примере:   `d="M780.5 169.6a42`

Вот как это выглядит :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У SVG стандартная, целочисленная величина - `1px` поэтому при рендеринге дробной части она добивается до целого серыми тонами.

[Посмотрите  ответ на Enso.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53794471/7394871)

Кратко:

1. Используйте целочисленные svg значения координат
2. Используйте атрибут `shape-render = "crispEdges"`
3. Если возможно изменение дизайна, избегайте контрастных цветов границ.

### Практические советы

- Если нужна стандартная иконка, то лучше взять готовую, которую
  рисовали профессионалы  Верный показатель - небольшой код

Если хочется нарисовать самостоятельно, то необходимо:

1. Выбирать минимально-достаточные размеры `viewBox`
2. Помнить, что ширина линии размещается симметрично относительно осевой.  Если ширина линии `4px`, то 2px будут внешними. Эта одна из причин подрезки контуров.

Ниже пример расположения линии шириной `1px` Видите по полпикселя относительно осевой

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3. Рисовать лучше только одиночными линиями, так как при двойном контуре невозможно сделать анимацию линий.

В вашем примере я нарисовал три линии, шириной 4px, концы линий закруглены `stroke-linecap:round;`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ниже код:

```html
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  height="10vh"
viewBox="0 0 40 40" version="1.1" style="border:1px solid red">
<style>
.s0{
 fill:none;
 stroke-linecap:round;
 stroke-width:4;
 stroke:#000;
}

</style>  
  <path d="M5 10 35 10" class="s0"/>
  <path d="M5 20 35 20" class="s0"/>
  <path d="M5 30 35 30" class="s0"/>
</svg>
```

Для изменения размера иконки, используйте - `height="10vh"`
Красная рамка показывает размеры холста SVG, удобно при отладке, после завершения удалите - `style="border:1px solid red"`

Comment: Не подскажите софт, в котором рисовали вектор?

Comment: @МаксимСиваконь Рисовал в Inkscape, в принципе можно в любом векторном редакторе После использовал оптимизатор  [SVG-EDITOR](https://petercollingridge.appspot.com/svg-editor)

Comment: я вот пользуюсь таким оптимизатором [nano](https://vecta.io/nano)

Comment: @МаксимСиваконь интересно, а он очищает от мусора, который оставляют за собой векторные редакторы или только сжимает SVG? Посмотрите я делал подборку инструментов для работы с SVG https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/925990/28748

Comment: Спасибо за статью, вообще я обратил внимание что он да удаляет лишний мусор после редакторов но и объединяет такие теги как `<path>`. После его оптимизации вес вектора становится гораздо меньше, например исходный вес `1 032 байт` а после оптимизации уже `577 байт`

Comment: @МаксимСиваконь Да не за что :) Но чаще нужно чтобы `path` были не объеденены  Я обычно убираю чекбоксы `Combine paths where possible` и `Remove whitespace` в режиме `Extreme (may alter image quality)` легче код читать. Вообще смотрите мой профиль и вы тоже полюбите SVG :)

Comment: Александр, да уж, действительно не просто ответ, а целая хорошая статья! Когда книгу по SVG начнёшь писать?

Comment: @Bharata Здравствуй дорогой! Долго будешь жить. Сегодня вспоминал тебя, - "куда,  Bharata надолго пропал :)"  [Сотни ответов на ruSO? Почему бы Вам не написать книгу?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/9303/28748)