# Почему не работает stroke-dashoffset в SVG?

Tags: html, css, svg, css-animation, smil

Есть один хороший [скрипт](https://codepen.io/jlison/pen/PZgVXJ), который к сожалению, работает только на сайте codepen.io.

Я пытаюсь портировать его на SVG. Сначала я делал с помощью `<animate>` и `<animateTransform>`. Но что-то не получалось, решил переделать на SVG+CSS. Но, получается тоже как-то не так. На скрипте, что на сайте codepen, часы работают как-то по-живому. А у меня получаются какие-то с нереальной физикой.

```css
html,
      body {
        min-height: 100vh;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      body {
        background: #4873a9;
      }
      * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      svg {
        position: absolute;
        width: 600px;
        height: 600px;
        left: calc(50vw - 300px);
        top: calc(50vh - 300px);
      }
      :root {
        --animation-duration: 10s;
      }
      .topSand {
        animation: topSand var(--animation-duration) linear infinite;
      }
      .botSand {
        animation: botSand var(--animation-duration) linear infinite;
      }
      .topShadow {
        animation: topShadow var(--animation-duration) linear infinite;
      }
      .botShadow {
        animation: botShadow var(--animation-duration) linear infinite;
      }
      .rightShine {
        animation: rightShine var(--animation-duration) linear infinite;
      }
      .leftShine {
        animation: leftShine var(--animation-duration) linear infinite;
      }
      .allGrouped {
        animation: rotate var(--animation-duration) linear infinite;
        transform-origin: 306px 275px;
      }
      .drip {
        animation: drip var(--animation-duration) linear infinite;
        stroke-miterlimit: 10;
      }
      @keyframes topSand {
        0% {
          y: 90px;
        }
        90% {
          y: 280px;
        }
        100% {
          y: 280px;
        }
      }
      @keyframes botSand {
        0% {
          cy: 580px;
          rx: 47.5;
        }
        5% {
          cy: 580px;
          rx: 47.5;
        }
        90% {
          cy: 415px;
          rx: 247.5;
        }
        93% {
          cy: 415px;
          rx: 247.5;
        }
        100% {
          cy: 415px;
          rx: 247.5;
          cy: 375px;
        }
      }
      @keyframes rotate {
        0% {
          transform: rotate(0deg);
        }
        90% {
          transform: rotate(0deg);
        }
        100% {
          transform: rotate(180deg);
        }
      }
      @keyframes topShadow {
        0% {
          opacity: 0.12;
        }
        90% {
          opacity: 0.12;
        }
        100% {
          opacity: 0;
        }
      }
      @keyframes botShadow {
        0% {
          opacity: 0;
        }
        90% {
          opacity: 0;
        }
        100% {
          opacity: 0.12;
        }
      }
      @keyframes rightShine {
        0% {
          opacity: 0.1;
        }
        90% {
          opacity: 0.1;
        }
        100% {
          opacity: 0.28;
        }
      }
      @keyframes leftShine {
        0% {
          opacity: 0.28;
        }
        90% {
          opacity: 0.28;
        }
        100% {
          opacity: 0.1;
        }
      }
      @keyframes drip {
        0% {
          stroke-dashoffset: 180px;
          stroke-dasharray: 1px 86px;
        }
        5% {
          stroke-dashoffset: -186px;
          stroke-dasharray: 1px, 2px;
        }
        8% {
          stroke-dashoffset: 0;
          stroke-dasharray: 1px, 1px;
        }
        11% {
          stroke-dashoffset: -186px;
          stroke-dasharray: 1px, 0px;
        }
        84.9% {
          stroke-dashoffset: 0px;
          stroke-dasharray: 1px, 0px;
        }
        88% {
          stroke-dashoffset: 0px;
          stroke-dasharray: 1px, 1px;
        }
        89.9% {
          stroke-dashoffset: 0px;
          stroke-dasharray: 1px, 48px;
        }
        90% {
          stroke-dashoffset: -186px;
          stroke-dasharray: 0px, 196px;
        }
        100% {
          stroke-dashoffset: -186px;
          stroke-dasharray: 0px, 196px;
        }
      }
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 600 600" width="600" height="600" xml:space="preserve">
      <defs>
        <circle id="grain" cx="0" cy="0" r="1" fill="#F7E0B7"></circle>
        <clipPath id="topMask">
          <path
            class="topMask"
            fill="#6D00BF"
            d="M316.7,266.3c-0.2,0.1-3.7,1.5-4.8,2.5c0,0,0,0,0,0.1c-1.8,1.5-3.2,4.5-3.2,7.1l-1.6,0l-1.4,0c0-2.6-1.4-5.6-3.2-7.1c0,0,0-0.1,0-0.1c-1.1-1-4.6-2.5-4.8-2.5C237.1,249.5,195,174,188,91h119h119.3C419.3,174,377.2,249.5,316.7,266.3z"
          ></path>
        </clipPath>
        <clipPath id="botMask">
          <path
            class="botMask"
            fill="#6D00BF"
            d="M316.7,283.7c-0.2-0.1-3.7-1.5-4.8-2.5c0,0,0,0,0-0.1c-1.8-1.5-3.2-4.5-3.2-7.1l-1.6,0l-1.4,0c0,2.6-1.4,5.6-3.2,7.1c0,0,0,0.1,0,0.1c-1.1,1-4.6,2.5-4.8,2.5C237.1,300.5,195,376,188,459h119h119.3C419.3,376,377.2,300.5,316.7,283.7z"
          ></path>
        </clipPath>
      </defs>
      <g class="allGrouped">
        <g clip-path="url(#topMask)">
          <rect
            class="topSand"
            x="0"
            y="90"
            fill="#F7E0B7"
            width="600"
            height="185"
          ></rect>
        </g>
        <g clip-path="url(#botMask)">
          <ellipse
            class="botSand"
            fill="#F7E0B7"
            cx="307.5"
            cy="580"
            rx="47.5"
            ry="120"
          ></ellipse>
        </g>
        <rect
          class="top"
          x="175"
          y="70"
          fill="#F1AF31"
          width="263"
          height="21"
        ></rect>
        <line
          class="drip"
          fill="none"
          stroke="#F7E0B7"
          stroke-dashoffset="-186"
          stroke-dasharray="1, 1"
          stroke-width="2"
          stroke-miterlimit="10"
          x1="307"
          y1="275"
          x2="307"
          y2="460"
        ></line>
        <path
          class="body"
          opacity="0.23"
          fill="#FFFFFF"
          d="M432.2,459H180.8c4.3-90,49.8-165,108.7-175.2c6.1-1,10.3-5.2,10.3-8.8c0-3-4.2-7.8-10.3-8.8C230.6,256,185.2,180.5,180.8,91h251.3c-4.3,89.6-49.7,166.3-108.8,175.2c-6,0.9-10.2,6.1-10.2,8.8c0,2.7,4.3,7.9,10.2,8.8C382.5,292.7,427.8,369,432.2,459z"
        ></path>
        <path
          class="topShadow"
          fill="#121212"
          opacity="0.12"
          d="M432.5,91h-252c0.3,4.1,0.8,8.8,1.4,14h249.3C432,98.3,432.2,95,432.5,91z"
          style="opacity: 0.12"
        ></path>
        <path
          class="botShadow"
          fill="#121212"
          opacity="0"
          d="M432.5,459h-252c0.3-4.1,0.8-8.8,1.4-14h249.3C432,451.7,432.2,455,432.5,459z"
          style="opacity: 0"
        ></path>
        <path
          class="rightShine"
          opacity="0.10"
          fill="#FFFFFF"
          d="M316.6,283.8c-5.2-1.2-8-6.1-8-8.8c0-2.7,2.8-7.5,8-8.8c58.6-14,105.6-87,106.5-175.2h-22.8c-3.6,85.6-38.3,168.8-102.8,177.2c0,0,8,0.7,8,6.8c0,6.2-8,6.8-8,6.8c64.5,8.3,99.2,91.6,102.8,177.2h22.8C422.3,370.8,375.3,297.8,316.6,283.8z"
          style="opacity: 0.1"
        ></path>
        <path
          class="leftShine"
          opacity="0.28"
          fill="#FFFFFF"
          d="M297,283.8c5.2-1.2,8-6.1,8-8.8c0-2.7-2.8-7.5-8-8.8c-58.6-14-105.6-87-106.5-175.2h22.8c3.6,85.6,38.3,168.8,102.8,177.2c0,0-8,0.7-8,6.8c0,6.2,8,6.8,8,6.8c-64.5,8.3-99.2,91.6-102.8,177.2h-22.8C191.4,370.8,238.4,297.8,297,283.8z"
          style="opacity: 0.28"
        ></path>
        <rect
          class="bottom"
          x="175"
          y="459"
          fill="#F1AF31"
          width="263"
          height="21"
        ></rect>
      </g>
    </svg>
```

В общем, более конкретизирую вопрос.

Брызги песка, как у автора скрипта на codepen, я даже и не пытаюсь сделать. Но струя из точек песка, которая должна падать вниз, у меня то зависает в воздухе, то и вовсе летит вверх...

Хочу сделать струю из точек, которые с небольшой скоростью падают вниз. Для этого подкручиваю два свойства в CSS: `stroke-dasharray` и `stroke-dashoffset`. Свойство `stroke-dasharray` работает как надо. А на `stroke-dashoffset`, который должен отвечать за движение точек вниз, картинка вообще не реагирует.

Почему?

Comment: Спасибо за интересный вопрос, по моему он у вас первый по SVG?

Comment: Да я на самом деле, в svg разбираюсь еще довольно плохо. Вероятно, для их редактирования есть софт, который может упростить многие задачи. Я использую svg в случаях крайней необходимости. И редактирую их в текстовом редакторе (иногда для расчетов координат, использую калькулятор, в отдельных случаях LibreOfficeCalc). Я просто, даже с инструментарием не разобрался. А так, конечно, мне нравятся тонкие <b>svg-алгоритмы</b>, что-то в них есть особенное, как и в CSS. Правда SVG+CSS работает гораздо хуже чем `<animate>`, надо это тоже переделать обратно))

Comment: вспомогательный софт есть, несколько лет собираю подборку, [здесь на сайте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/925990/28748) но вот полноценного IDE для SVG пока не могу найти . Тоже пишу код в Notepad++

Comment: @Alexandr_TT Хорошая идея, объединить векторную графику и IDE. И на мой взгляд, легче текстовый редактор прикрутить к Inkscape, чем векторный редактор картинок к IDE). А также, к моему большому сожалению, inkscape не работает на макинтошах. :-( Есть macSVG, но там... это один из маленьких инструментов для чего-то одного... То есть, macSVG не приспособлен к работе никак. Остаётся только Illustrator. Но он денег стоит. А душой я ближе к опенсурсу. Кстати, в вашем списке нет [potrace](http://potrace.sourceforge.net/). Это очень мощная штука, когда если уметь ей пользоваться...

Comment: @Alexandr_TT  А так, я бы рад конечно заниматься svg или просто классными фундоментальными загадками... Но на меня уже косо смотрят, когда видят что я сижу на SO. Дела стоят, прокрастинация... Меня вычислили, я захожу на SO чтобы убежать от своих проблем, то есть не делать свои дела.))

Comment: potrace, как и другие программы преобразования растра в вектор может быть и полезны в некоторых случаях, но я отказался от них в свое время. Код на выходе получается гигантский, запутанный. Все линии получаются с двойным контуром, поэтому их анимировать невозможно, невозможно стилизовать внутренние области, ограниченный этими контурами. То есть пользы от таких программ только - получить векторное изображение с которым довольно трудно работать.

Comment: Еще прошу прощения, про potrace я скинул не ту ссылку. Правильная [http://potracegui.sourceforge.net/](http://potracegui.sourceforge.net/). Сам инструмент консольный, алгоритм написан еще в 2003г. Но без GUI его использовать сложно. А в inscape какой-то урезанный GUI, не раскрывает его возможностей...

Comment: @Alexandr_TT c potrace нужна сноровка. Сам алгоритм гениален. Благодаря своей командной природе - его можно использовать в скриптах. Совместно с другими инструментами квантизации и imagemagick можно добиться идеально векторизованых изображений. Обязательно посмотрите скрипты [Fred's ImageMagick Scripts](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/index.php) и [Snibgo's ImageMagick pages](https://im.snibgo.com/). По крайней мере, уровни возможностей этих скриптов надо знать. Это может быть полезным при работе с графикой.

Comment: Просто potrace хорошо кушает только двухцветный несжатый bitmap. От того, на сколько грамотно разбить изображение на несколько уровней для последовательной обработки, зависит размер и качество картинки. Я понимаю, про что вы говорите, необработанное изображение выйдет в svg под 100мб и несколько часов трассировки.) Но если подойти к делу с умом - то будет выходить идеальнее чем вручную....

Comment: Благодарю за полезные ссылки, я их сохраню. Вполне возможно, что я однобоко подошёл к этому вопросу и не оценил все возможности.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**SMIL SVG**

На основе логики ТС, отвечая на основные вопросы:

> Почему не работает stroke-dashoffset в SVG?

С помощью тега `<animate>` и атрибута `attributeName` возможно задать анимацию свойств `stroke-dashoffset` (смещение пунктирной обводки относительно первоначального положения) и `stroke-dasharray`(вид пунктирной обводки). Значения указанных атрибутов, как и любых других, будут также изменяться со стартового значения и до конечного с определенным интервалом.

> ...струя из точек песка, которая должна падать вниз, у меня то
> зависает в воздухе, то и вовсе летит вверх...

Для того, чтобы воспроизвести реальное падение песка вниз, необходимо включить в анимацию не только выше перечисленные свойства, но также еще и координаты (атрибуты `y1` и `y2`) вертикальной оси элемента, значения которых будут меняться как на начальном этапе пересыпания песка через горловину, так и на конечном.

```css
body {margin: 0; background: #4873a9;}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 600 600" width="600" height="600" xml:space="preserve">

<defs>
<circle id="grain" cx="0" cy="0" r="1" fill="#F7E0B7"></circle>

<clipPath id="topMask">
<path class="topMask" fill="#6D00BF" d="M316.7,266.3c-0.2,0.1-3.7,1.5-4.8,2.5c0,0,0,0,0,0.1c-1.8,1.5-3.2,4.5-3.2,7.1l-1.6,0l-1.4,0c0-2.6-1.4-5.6-3.2-7.1c0,0,0-0.1,0-0.1c-1.1-1-4.6-2.5-4.8-2.5C237.1,249.5,195,174,188,91h119h119.3C419.3,174,377.2,249.5,316.7,266.3z"></path>
</clipPath>

<clipPath id="botMask">
<path class="botMask" fill="#6D00BF" d="M316.7,283.7c-0.2-0.1-3.7-1.5-4.8-2.5c0,0,0,0,0-0.1c-1.8-1.5-3.2-4.5-3.2-7.1l-1.6,0l-1.4,0c0,2.6-1.4,5.6-3.2,7.1c0,0,0,0.1,0,0.1c-1.1,1-4.6,2.5-4.8,2.5C237.1,300.5,195,376,188,459h119h119.3C419.3,376,377.2,300.5,316.7,283.7z"></path>
</clipPath>

</defs>

<g id="allGrouped" transform-origin="306px 275px">

<!--Трансформация часов-->
<animateTransform id="rotate" href="#allGrouped" attributeType="xml" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" additive="replace" calcMode="linear" values="0; 180;" dur="1s" begin="drip1.end+1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>
<animateTransform id="rotate__revers" href="#allGrouped" attributeType="xml" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" additive="replace" values="180; 0;" dur="0.0001s" begin="rotate.end" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>

<!--Верхний сосуд-->
<g clip-path="url(#topMask)">
<rect id="topSand" x="0" y="90" fill="#F7E0B7" width="600" height="185"></rect>
</g>
<!--Анимация песка в верхнем сосуде-->
<animate id="topS" href="#topSand" attributeName="y" calcMode="linear" from="90" to="280" dur="8s" begin="rotate__revers.end+1s;1.5s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>
<animate id="topS_rev" href="#topSand" attributeName="y" calcMode="linear" from="280" to="90" dur="0.0001s" begin="rotate.end" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>

<!--Нижний сосуд-->
<g clip-path="url(#botMask)">
<ellipse id="botSand" fill="#F7E0B7" cx="307.5" cy="580" rx="47.5" ry="120"></ellipse>
<!--Анимация песка в нижнем сосуде-->
<animate id="botS1" href="#botSand" attributeName="cy" calcMode="linear" from="580" to="415" dur="7.4s" begin="rotate__revers.end+1.5s;2s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>
<animate id="botS2" href="#botSand" attributeName="rx" calcMode="linear" from="47.5" to="247.5" dur="7.4s" begin="rotate__revers.end+1.5s;2s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>
<animate id="botS1_rev" href="#botSand" attributeName="cy" calcMode="linear" from="415" to="580" dur="0.0001s" begin="rotate.end" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>
<animate id="botS2_rev" href="#botSand" attributeName="rx" calcMode="linear" from="247.5" to="47.5" dur="0.0001s" begin="rotate.end" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>
</g>

<rect class="top" x="175" y="70" fill="#F1AF31" width="263" height="21"></rect>

<!--Песок пересыпается через горловину-->
<line id="drip" fill="none" stroke="#F7E0B7" stroke-dashoffset="-186" stroke-dasharray="1, 1" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="307" y1="275" x2="307" y2="275"></line>
<!--start Меняем координаты в начале-->
<animate id="drip02" href="#drip" attributeName="y2" calcMode="linear" values="275; 460;" dur="0.5s" begin="rotate__revers.end+1s;1.5s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>
<animate id="drip02_rev" href="#drip" attributeName="y2" calcMode="linear" values="460; 275;" dur="0.0001s" begin="drip02.end+9.5s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>
<!--end Меняем координаты в конце-->
<animate id="drip01" href="#drip" attributeName="y1" calcMode="linear" values="275; 459;" dur="1s" begin="rotate__revers.end+8.8s;9.3s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>
<animate id="drip01_rev" href="#drip" attributeName="y1" calcMode="linear" values="459; 275;" dur="0.0001s" begin="drip01.end+2s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>
<!--Анимация песка, который пересыпается через горловину-->
<animate id="drip1" href="#drip" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" calcMode="linear" values="-186px; 186px; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; -186px;" dur="10s" begin="rotate__revers.end;1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>
<animate id="drip2" href="#drip" attributeName="stroke-dasharray" calcMode="linear" values="1,86; 1,2; 1,1; 1,0; 1,0; 1,0; 1,0; 1,0; 1,0; 1,0; 1,0; 1,0; 1,86;" dur="10s" begin="rotate__revers.end;1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>

<path class="body" opacity="0.23" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M432.2,459H180.8c4.3-90,49.8-165,108.7-175.2c6.1-1,10.3-5.2,10.3-8.8c0-3-4.2-7.8-10.3-8.8C230.6,256,185.2,180.5,180.8,91h251.3c-4.3,89.6-49.7,166.3-108.8,175.2c-6,0.9-10.2,6.1-10.2,8.8c0,2.7,4.3,7.9,10.2,8.8C382.5,292.7,427.8,369,432.2,459z"></path>

<!--Полоска верх-->
<path id="topShadow" fill="#121212" d="M432.5,91h-252c0.3,4.1,0.8,8.8,1.4,14h249.3C432,98.3,432.2,95,432.5,91z" opacity="0.12"></path>
<!--Анимация верхней полоски-->
<animate id="topS" href="#topShadow" attributeName="opacity" calcMode="linear" from="0.12" to="0" dur="0.5s" begin="rotate.end-0.5s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>
<animate id="topS_rot" href="#topShadow" attributeName="opacity" calcMode="linear" from="0" to="0.12" dur="0.001s" begin="rotate.end" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>

<!--Полоска низ-->
<path id="botShadow" fill="#121212" d="M432.5,459h-252c0.3-4.1,0.8-8.8,1.4-14h249.3C432,451.7,432.2,455,432.5,459z" opacity="0"></path>
<!--Анимация нижней полоски-->
<animate id="botS" href="#botShadow" attributeName="opacity" calcMode="linear" from="0" to="0.12" dur="1s" begin="rotate.end-1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>
<animate id="botS_rot" href="#botShadow" attributeName="opacity" calcMode="linear" from="0.12" to="0" dur="0.0001s" begin="rotate.end+0.0001s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>

<!--Отблеск справа-->
<path id="rightShine" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M316.6,283.8c-5.2-1.2-8-6.1-8-8.8c0-2.7,2.8-7.5,8-8.8c58.6-14,105.6-87,106.5-175.2h-22.8c-3.6,85.6-38.3,168.8-102.8,177.2c0,0,8,0.7,8,6.8c0,6.2-8,6.8-8,6.8c64.5,8.3,99.2,91.6,102.8,177.2h22.8C422.3,370.8,375.3,297.8,316.6,283.8z" opacity="0.1"></path>
<!--Анимация отблеска справа-->
<animate id="rightS" href="#rightShine" attributeName="opacity" calcMode="linear" from="0.1" to="0.28" dur="1s" begin="rotate.end-1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>
<animate id="rightS_rot" href="#rightShine" attributeName="opacity" calcMode="linear" from="0.28" to="0.1" dur="0.0001s" begin="rotate.end+0.0001s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>

<!--Отблеск слева-->
<path id="leftShine" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M297,283.8c5.2-1.2,8-6.1,8-8.8c0-2.7-2.8-7.5-8-8.8c-58.6-14-105.6-87-106.5-175.2h22.8c3.6,85.6,38.3,168.8,102.8,177.2c0,0-8,0.7-8,6.8c0,6.2,8,6.8,8,6.8c-64.5,8.3-99.2,91.6-102.8,177.2h-22.8C191.4,370.8,238.4,297.8,297,283.8z" opacity="0.28"></path>
<!--Анимация отблеска слева-->
<animate id="leftS" href="#leftShine" attributeName="opacity" calcMode="linear" from="0.28" to="0.1" dur="1s" begin="rotate.end-1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>
<animate id="leftS_rot" href="#leftShine" attributeName="opacity" calcMode="linear" from="0.1" to="0.28" dur="0.0001s" begin="rotate.end+0.0001s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>

<rect class="bottom" x="175" y="459" fill="#F1AF31" width="263" height="21"></rect>

</g>

</svg>
```

*В планах, по мере возможности в смысле времени, полностью поменять логику, а также дополнительно еще реализовать задачу с помощью только CSS. Но только в планах, ибо требования такие в вопросе не указаны.*

**UPD/**

Исправил мелкие недочеты. А также:

> Брызги песка, как у автора скрипта на codepen, я даже и не пытаюсь
> сделать.

Воспроизвести анимацию "брызги песка" возможно с помощью атрибута `transform` и свойства `translate`. Ниже пример, выполненный на скорую руку, исключительно для демонстрации. Для этой реализации использовалось только одно выше указанное свойство и ничего не усложнялось, главная цель это передать мысль.

```css
body {
 width: 100%; min-height: 100vh; margin: 0; background: #4873a9;
 display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: center; align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 600 600" width="600" height="600" xml:space="preserve">

<defs>
<circle id="grain" cx="0" cy="0" r="1" fill="#F7E0B7"></circle>

<clipPath id="topMask">
<path class="topMask" fill="#6D00BF" d="M316.7,266.3c-0.2,0.1-3.7,1.5-4.8,2.5c0,0,0,0,0,0.1c-1.8,1.5-3.2,4.5-3.2,7.1l-1.6,0l-1.4,0c0-2.6-1.4-5.6-3.2-7.1c0,0,0-0.1,0-0.1c-1.1-1-4.6-2.5-4.8-2.5C237.1,249.5,195,174,188,91h119h119.3C419.3,174,377.2,249.5,316.7,266.3z"></path>
</clipPath>

<clipPath id="botMask">
<path class="botMask" fill="#6D00BF" d="M316.7,283.7c-0.2-0.1-3.7-1.5-4.8-2.5c0,0,0,0,0-0.1c-1.8-1.5-3.2-4.5-3.2-7.1l-1.6,0l-1.4,0c0,2.6-1.4,5.6-3.2,7.1c0,0,0,0.1,0,0.1c-1.1,1-4.6,2.5-4.8,2.5C237.1,300.5,195,376,188,459h119h119.3C419.3,376,377.2,300.5,316.7,283.7z"></path>
</clipPath>

</defs>

<g id="allGrouped" transform-origin="306px 275px">

<!--Трансформация часов-->
<animateTransform id="rotate" href="#allGrouped" attributeType="xml" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" additive="replace" calcMode="linear" values="0; 180;" dur="1s" begin="drip1.end+1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>
<animateTransform id="rotate__revers" href="#allGrouped" attributeType="xml" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" additive="replace" values="180; 0;" dur="0.0001s" begin="rotate.end" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>

<!--Верхний сосуд-->
<g clip-path="url(#topMask)">
<rect id="topSand" x="0" y="90" fill="#F7E0B7" width="600" height="185"></rect>
</g>
<!--Анимация песка в верхнем сосуде-->
<animate id="topS" href="#topSand" attributeName="y" calcMode="linear" from="90" to="280" dur="8s" begin="rotate__revers.end+1s;1.5s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>
<animate id="topS_rev" href="#topSand" attributeName="y" calcMode="linear" values="80;90" dur="1s" begin="rotate.end" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>

<!--Нижний сосуд-->
<g clip-path="url(#botMask)">
<ellipse id="botSand" fill="#F7E0B7" cx="307.5" cy="580" rx="47.5" ry="120"></ellipse>
<!--Анимация песка в нижнем сосуде-->
<animate id="botS1" href="#botSand" attributeName="cy" calcMode="linear" from="580" to="415" dur="7.4s" begin="rotate__revers.end+1.5s;2s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>
<animate id="botS2" href="#botSand" attributeName="rx" calcMode="linear" from="47.5" to="247.5" dur="7.4s" begin="rotate__revers.end+1.5s;2s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>
<animate id="botS1_rev" href="#botSand" attributeName="cy" calcMode="linear" from="415" to="580" dur="0.0001s" begin="rotate.end" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>
<animate id="botS2_rev" href="#botSand" attributeName="rx" calcMode="linear" from="247.5" to="47.5" dur="0.0001s" begin="rotate.end" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>
</g>

<rect class="top" x="175" y="70" fill="#F1AF31" width="263" height="21"></rect>

<!--Песок пересыпается через горловину-->
<line id="drip" fill="none" stroke="#F7E0B7" stroke-dashoffset="-186" stroke-dasharray="1, 1" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="307" y1="275" x2="307" y2="275"></line>
<!--start Меняем координаты в начале-->
<animate id="drip02" href="#drip" attributeName="y2" calcMode="linear" values="275; 460;" dur="0.5s" begin="rotate__revers.end+1s;1.5s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>
<animate id="drip02_rev" href="#drip" attributeName="y2" calcMode="linear" values="460; 275;" dur="0.0001s" begin="drip02.end+9.5s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>
<!--end Меняем координаты в конце-->
<animate id="drip01" href="#drip" attributeName="y1" calcMode="linear" values="275; 459;" dur="1s" begin="rotate__revers.end+8.8s;9.3s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>
<animate id="drip01_rev" href="#drip" attributeName="y1" calcMode="linear" values="459; 275;" dur="0.0001s" begin="drip01.end+2s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>
<!--Анимация песка, который пересыпается через горловину-->
<animate id="drip1" href="#drip" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" calcMode="linear" values="-186px; 186px; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; -186px;" dur="10s" begin="rotate__revers.end;1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>
<animate id="drip2" href="#drip" attributeName="stroke-dasharray" calcMode="linear" values="1,86; 1,2; 1,1; 1,0; 1,0; 1,0; 1,0; 1,0; 1,0; 1,0; 1,0; 1,0; 1,86;" dur="10s" begin="rotate__revers.end;1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>

<path class="body" opacity="0.23" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M432.2,459H180.8c4.3-90,49.8-165,108.7-175.2c6.1-1,10.3-5.2,10.3-8.8c0-3-4.2-7.8-10.3-8.8C230.6,256,185.2,180.5,180.8,91h251.3c-4.3,89.6-49.7,166.3-108.8,175.2c-6,0.9-10.2,6.1-10.2,8.8c0,2.7,4.3,7.9,10.2,8.8C382.5,292.7,427.8,369,432.2,459z"></path>

<!--Полоска верх-->
<path id="topShadow" fill="#121212" d="M432.5,91h-252c0.3,4.1,0.8,8.8,1.4,14h249.3C432,98.3,432.2,95,432.5,91z" opacity="0.12"></path>
<!--Анимация верхней полоски-->
<animate id="topS" href="#topShadow" attributeName="opacity" calcMode="linear" from="0.12" to="0" dur="0.5s" begin="rotate.end-0.5s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>
<animate id="topS_rot" href="#topShadow" attributeName="opacity" calcMode="linear" from="0" to="0.12" dur="0.001s" begin="rotate.end" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>

<!--Полоска низ-->
<path id="botShadow" fill="#121212" d="M432.5,459h-252c0.3-4.1,0.8-8.8,1.4-14h249.3C432,451.7,432.2,455,432.5,459z" opacity="0"></path>
<!--Анимация нижней полоски-->
<animate id="botS" href="#botShadow" attributeName="opacity" calcMode="linear" from="0" to="0.12" dur="1s" begin="rotate.end-1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>
<animate id="botS_rot" href="#botShadow" attributeName="opacity" calcMode="linear" from="0.12" to="0" dur="0.0001s" begin="rotate.end+0.0001s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>

<!--Отблеск справа-->
<path id="rightShine" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M316.6,283.8c-5.2-1.2-8-6.1-8-8.8c0-2.7,2.8-7.5,8-8.8c58.6-14,105.6-87,106.5-175.2h-22.8c-3.6,85.6-38.3,168.8-102.8,177.2c0,0,8,0.7,8,6.8c0,6.2-8,6.8-8,6.8c64.5,8.3,99.2,91.6,102.8,177.2h22.8C422.3,370.8,375.3,297.8,316.6,283.8z" opacity="0.1"></path>
<!--Анимация отблеска справа-->
<animate id="rightS" href="#rightShine" attributeName="opacity" calcMode="linear" from="0.1" to="0.28" dur="1s" begin="rotate.end-1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>
<animate id="rightS_rot" href="#rightShine" attributeName="opacity" calcMode="linear" from="0.28" to="0.1" dur="0.0001s" begin="rotate.end+0.0001s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>

<!--Отблеск слева-->
<path id="leftShine" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M297,283.8c5.2-1.2,8-6.1,8-8.8c0-2.7-2.8-7.5-8-8.8c-58.6-14-105.6-87-106.5-175.2h22.8c3.6,85.6,38.3,168.8,102.8,177.2c0,0-8,0.7-8,6.8c0,6.2,8,6.8,8,6.8c-64.5,8.3-99.2,91.6-102.8,177.2h-22.8C191.4,370.8,238.4,297.8,297,283.8z" opacity="0.28"></path>
<!--Анимация отблеска слева-->
<animate id="leftS" href="#leftShine" attributeName="opacity" calcMode="linear" from="0.28" to="0.1" dur="1s" begin="rotate.end-1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>
<animate id="leftS_rot" href="#leftShine" attributeName="opacity" calcMode="linear" from="0.1" to="0.28" dur="0.0001s" begin="rotate.end+0.0001s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>

<!--Брызги песка-->
<g clip-path="url(#botMask)"> 
<g id="grainGroup" transform="translate(307,0)" opacity="0">

<use id="gr1" xlink:href="#grain" fill="#F7E0B7" width="1" height="1" x="0" y="0" transform="translate(0,0)"/>
<use id="gr2" xlink:href="#grain" fill="#F7E0B7" width="1" height="1" x="0" y="0" transform="translate(0,0)"/>
<use id="gr3" xlink:href="#grain" fill="#F7E0B7" width="1" height="1" x="0" y="0" transform="translate(0,0)"/>
<use id="gr4" xlink:href="#grain" fill="#F7E0B7" width="1" height="1" x="0" y="0" transform="translate(0,0)"/>
<use id="gr5" xlink:href="#grain" fill="#F7E0B7" width="1" height="1" x="0" y="0" transform="translate(0,0)"/>
<use id="gr6" xlink:href="#grain" fill="#F7E0B7" width="1" height="1" x="0" y="0" transform="translate(0,0)"/>
<use id="gr7" xlink:href="#grain" fill="#F7E0B7" width="1" height="1" x="0" y="0" transform="translate(0,0)"/>
<use id="gr8" xlink:href="#grain" fill="#F7E0B7" width="1" height="1" x="0" y="0" transform="translate(0,0)"/>

<animateTransform id="grG" href="#grainGroup" attributeType="xml" attributeName="transform" type="translate" additive="replace" values="307,460; 307,295" dur="7.4s" begin="rotate__revers.end+1.5s;2s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>
<animate id="grG_op1" href="#grainGroup" attributeName="opacity" calcMode="linear" from="0" to="1" dur="0.0001s" begin="rotate__revers.end+1.6s;2.1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>
<animate id="grG_op0" href="#grainGroup" attributeName="opacity" calcMode="linear" from="1" to="0" dur="0.0001s" begin="rotate__revers.end+8.9s;9.4s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>

<animateTransform id="grG1" href="#gr1" attributeType="xml" attributeName="transform" type="translate" additive="replace" values="0,0; 30,-12" dur="0.4s" begin="rotate__revers.end+1.5s;2s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite"/>

<animateTransform id="grG2" href="#gr2" attributeType="xml" attributeName="transform" type="translate" additive="replace" values="0,0; -20,-10" dur="0.4s" begin="rotate__revers.end+1.6s;2.1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite"/>

<animateTransform id="grG3" href="#gr3" attributeType="xml" attributeName="transform" type="translate" additive="replace" values="0,0; 18,-15" dur="0.4s" begin="rotate__revers.end+1.7s;2.2s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite"/>

<animateTransform id="grG4" href="#gr4" attributeType="xml" attributeName="transform" type="translate" additive="replace" values="0,0; -16,-12" dur="0.4s" begin="rotate__revers.end+1.8s;2.3s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite"/>

<animateTransform id="grG5" href="#gr5" attributeType="xml" attributeName="transform" type="translate" additive="replace" values="0,0; -23,-5" dur="0.4s" begin="rotate__revers.end+1.9s;2.4s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite"/>

<animateTransform id="grG6" href="#gr6" attributeType="xml" attributeName="transform" type="translate" additive="replace" values="0,0; 19,-11" dur="0.4s" begin="rotate__revers.end+2s;2.5s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite"/>

<animateTransform id="grG7" href="#gr7" attributeType="xml" attributeName="transform" type="translate" additive="replace" values="0,0; -28,-8" dur="0.4s" begin="rotate__revers.end+2.1s;2.6s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite"/>

<animateTransform id="grG8" href="#gr8" attributeType="xml" attributeName="transform" type="translate" additive="replace" values="0,0; 28,-12" dur="0.4s" begin="rotate__revers.end+2.2s;2.7s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite"/>

</g>
</g>

<rect class="bottom" x="175" y="459" fill="#F1AF31" width="263" height="21"></rect>

</g>

</svg>
```

Comment: Брызги (струйки песка) классно смотрятся!  additive="replace"  - значение по умолчанию Можно не добавлять